# Installing Windows Server 2012 Preview on an Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, mount, amazon-ebs, windows-server-2012, installation

Is there any way of doing a clean install on an Amazon EC2 instance. I have the bootable installation media stored in an EBS volume. How can I boot from that volume?  And do I have to use an automated install (install script) then, since I won't be able to oversee the boot procedure and all the settings that need attention during the installation process.

Comment: And why are you bothering with a preview when the software has been released?

Comment: Well... You're right :-) It was just out of curiosity.  But still, it might be possible to script an unattended installation started  from an AMI I've made myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to do this. EC2 does not support booting from anything but AMI images.

You'll need to wait until they release an official 2012 image.